# Unable to deploy Azure ARM with parameters using az cli from powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

Trying simple deployment with parameters from a PS script:

```
$prefix = "xxx"
$location = "switzerlandnorth"
az deployment group create `
    --name  $timestamp  `
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
    --mode incremental `
    --verbose `
    --template-file .\src\ops\scripts\arm.json `
    --parameters "{ `"location`": { `"value`": `"$location`" },`"projectPrefix`": { `"value`": `"$prefix`" } }"
```

Response with error:

```
Unable to parse parameter: { location: { value: switzerlandnorth }, projectPrefix: { value: xxx } }
```

**Running from a PS1 script**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in the error that it is unable to parse the parameters. The correct way to pass the parameters to the `az deployment group create` command is:

```
 az deployment group create `
 --name  $timestamp  `
 --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
 --mode "incremental" `
 --verbose `
 --template-file ".\src\ops\scripts\arm.json" `
 --parameters '{ \"location\": { \"value\": \"switzerlandnorth\" },\"projectPrefix\": { \"value\": \"xxx\" } }'
```

**Update:**

If you want to pass the PowerShell variables in the Parameters you can do something like below -

```
 $location = "switzerlandnorth"
 $projectPrefix = "xxx"
 $params = '{ \"location\": { \"value\": \" ' + $location + '\" },\"projectPrefix\": { \"value\": \"' + $projectprefix + '\" } }' 
 az deployment group create `
 --name  $timestamp  `
 --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
 --mode "incremental" `
 --verbose `
 --template-file ".\src\ops\scripts\arm.json" `
 --parameters $params
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: TI need to use double quotes to be able to fragments with valiable values. I'm going to update the example to be more clear. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7

Comment: Updated. Using ' instead " is not replacing the variable value.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to pass PS variable values to parameters right?

Comment: Yes, like in the example.  $prefix in the string will be replaced by xxx

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your updated query. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I think that this way to interpolate strings is not too elegante, but definible working and maybe It's the Microsoft PowerShell way. So thanks a lot !!

Comment: Nowadays you can also use it like this:  `az deployment group create --resource-group testgroup --template-file demotemplate.json --parameters exampleString='inline string' exampleArray='("value1", "value2")'`

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can think of this is using objects/hashtables in PS and then converting to JSON, e.g.

```
$param = @{
  location = "switzerlandnorth"
  prefix = "foo"
}

$paramJSON = ($param | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 30 -Compress).Replace('"', '\"') # escape quotes in order to pass the command via pwsh.exe

az deployment group create -g $resourceGroupName--template-file "azuredeploy.json" -p $paramJson
```

This is a similar example:
https://gist.github.com/bmoore-msft/d578c815f319af7eb20d9d97df9bf657

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw in my two cents here because previous answers are slim on what we are actually doing here. In short the `az deployment group create` command wants the `--parameters` argument to be a double serialized JSON string {scoff}. In order to create a value that can be handled by `az deployment group create` we would need to do something like this:

```
$stupidlyFormattedParam = @{
  someAppSetting1 = @{ value = "setting 1" }
  someAppSetting2 = @{ value = "setting 2" }
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 10 | ConvertTo-Json

az deployment group create --name someName--resource-group someGroup --parameters $stupidlyFormattedParam --template-file .\someFile.json
```